# Importing a function into a file yields results of a function run with inputs other than those the func is called with

Tags: python

when i import a python file(let's call it function file 1 ) that contains a function that i need in another python file(let's call it file 2) and call the function from file 2 using different function inputs, i get the results that i expect from file 1( when calling the function according to the inputs of file 1 ) and then i get the results that i want( from running the function in file 2 with the new function inputs). What could be the reason for that?

file 2 should call the function jacobi from the file Jacobi_Iteration and give the two arrays A,f and x(guess array) as inputs and the function"jacobi" should return x and stor it in ans_s. What calling the function, however, does is to call jacobi and give it old inputs that were used for calling jacobi in the file Jacobi_Iterations and then call jacobi with inputs given in file 2. The end result is getting the results expected from the old inputs and then those of the new inputs after each other in the results pane. Of course, i tried not calling jacobi in Jacobi_Iterations and only calling it in file2, but in vain.

Remarks:
Both functions are present in the same directory

This is file 2:

```
import numpy
import numpy.linalg as nl
from Jacobi_Iteration import jacobi

A = numpy.array([[72.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0],
                [0.0,38.0,0.0,0.0,0.0],
                [72.0,38.0,-160.0,0.0,0.0],
                [0.0,0.0,160.0,-185.0,0.0],
                [0.0,0.0,0.0,180.0,-215.0]])
f = numpy.array([180.0,810.0,-630.0,-2750.0,-3820.0])
# sol = nl.solve(A,f)
#print("sol=",sol)

# solving using the jacobi iteration
x = [15.0,15.0,15.0,15.0,15.0]
ans_2 = jacobi(A,f,x)
print(ans_2)
```

This is the function file"Jacobi_Iterations"

```
import numpy
import numpy.linalg as nl
def jacobi(A,f,x,maxIter=100,tol=0.0001):
    # x is the guess vector
    xnew = numpy.copy(x)
    n = f.size
    # Checking for the dimensions of the matrices
    if (A.shape[0] != n) or (A.shape[1] != n):
        print("Incorrect dimentions !")
        return f
    # Generating new guesses and seeing whether A.x will converge during the maxIter
    for iter in range(maxIter):
        # checking if the guess vector satisfies the tol:
        res = f - numpy.dot(A,x)
        if ( nl.norm(res,2)  < tol ):
            print("converged after",iter,"iterations!")
            return x
        # Getting a better guess vector x:
        for i in range(n):
            sum = 0.0
            for j in range(n):
                if (i != j):
                    sum+= A[i,j] * x[j]
            xnew[i] = (f[i] - sum)/A[i,i]
        x = numpy.copy(xnew)
    return x
```

Answer (score 0):

Python by default will look for packages in some pre-determined places. Working dir might be a candidate

It might not be the case for you but try to find out if there are conflicts with these.
I had this prob in the past

This is a nice link:
https://leemendelowitz.github.io/blog/how-does-python-find-packages.html